# Decode string retrieved from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I am using `php 7.1.8` and I am having the following string saved in my mysql database:

`$dat = a:5:{i:0;s:4:"6162";i:1;s:4:"6160";i:2;s:4:"6236";i:3;s:4:"6326";i:4;s:4:"6308";}`

I tried to convert `$dat` with the following:

`$dat = json_decode($dat, true);`

However, the `json_decode()` returns `null`.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How  the data was inserted?

Comment: @juanbits I think the data was inserted by the `advanced-custom-field` wordpress plugin.

Comment: `unserialize()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is obviously a Serialized array so we use

```
unserialize()
```

Not

```
json_decode();
```

How do I know, these `a:5:{..}`  `i:0` and `s:4:"6162"` this is the type and the number/count/length.  So `a` is array with 5 items,  `int 0` and `string 4` "6162".

If this was JSON it would be something like  `'["6162","6160","6308" ... ]'`. As you can see JSON takes considerably less room, as well.

But, this is the form that serialize takes.  That said there is a special serialize that is used for session, that I am not as familiar with, but I don't think this is that one especially if this is from wordpress.

One word of caution, while Json can be manually edited rather strait forward, don't attempt that with this type of serialization, it can be done but it invites disaster .... lol

In general you can think of them as the same class of functions, they both convert complex structures to a string.  Serialize has the benefit (if you want to call it that) of storing whole objects in the string, which is something JSON can't natively do.  But (serialize) is a PHP thing though so it makes the data less portable. Even less so if you save objects, that's why I said it might be a benefit, it should be done only after some consideration is given to the future use of this data because it can only be used by PHP and only if those classes saved in it are still accessible (if objects are saved).

This is why a lot of times you might see JSON used instead of serialize.

```
 $dat = 'a:5:{i:0;s:4:"6162";i:1;s:4:"6160";i:2;s:4:"6236";i:3;s:4:"6326";i:4;s:4:"6308";}';
 var_export(unserialize($dat));
```

OUTPUT

```
array (
  0 => '6162',
  1 => '6160',
  2 => '6236',
  3 => '6326',
  4 => '6308',
);
```

Test it live [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e6295dbf6138a46a46647784f055f3521cf691c7)

Answer (score 1):

Find the answer here

```
$dat = 'a:5:{i:0;s:4:"6162";i:1;s:4:"6160";i:2;s:4:"6236";i:3;s:4:"6326";i:4;s:4:"6308";}';
$arr = unserialize($dat);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: You missed a bracket when you copied the `$dat` variable `a:5:i:0` should be `a:5:{i:0`